# equal height table cells in html table

Tags: html, css, html-table

what do I want?

**Dynamic content! it must be possible to add arbitrary amounts of content to table column 1, and column 2, and the result must still work. Fixed heights are not a solution.**

using html tables and css:

[image]

so in prosa: the content must be equal height of both table cells, and the content of the less full cell, needs to be at the vertical extremes. The content of the less full cell is a little div that looks like a green line, and text. Those are 2 separate items and I want these 2 items to align at the extremes of the table

codepen: https://codepen.io/jossnaz/pen/YBGEGb

```css
table {
  width: 300px;
}

td {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.separator {
  height: 1px;
  background-color: green;
  width: 50px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>111111111111 <br> 111 <br> 111</td>
      <td>222 222 222 22222222
        <div class="separator"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

somehow the table cell is not letting me do what I want.

Comment: I think I'm missing the question. When you fill 2 cells in the same row, with different contents, the cells always have the same height. This is also what I see on your codepen. What is it that you would like to change in your codepen?

Comment: also why not Flexbox or CSS grid? you have this by default then simply align separtor at the bottom

Comment: I understand this is an alignment issue. If so, adding `vertical-align: top` to your CSS for `td` should be enough. Otherwise, make clear what your expected result is (via image if possible). Thanks.

Comment: also note that margin:auto will give you 0 for top and bottom

Comment: I realized the green line is somehow not obvious enough. I want it to align at the bottom. I updated the image, you can click on the image, and see it bigger

Comment: @TemaniAfif I simplified the example from the real use case. Tables help a lot with making dynamic content fit. Yes you can use flex box somehow, and it will work, but it can be a lot more complex than you might think. And: its a table and it doesnt need to be responsive. Btw css grid? the last time I tried to do the most basic thing with it, IE11 wouldnt display it properly. So CSS grid? We can be happy that IE11 displays flex box more or less okay.

Comment: ok, but your simplified example can be handled easily like for example making the separator absolute position or change it with a simple background. I guess it won't help you if it's done like that?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I guess with `position: absolute` I could live, even though its usually last resort

Comment: and what about this https://jsfiddle.net/0edLn7hp/ ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif the problem is if its not exactly that green thingy, then it won't work. But If you give the relative / absolute position solution as answer, I will accept it. I thought there is a better solution than that, I really thought so. But I guess there is a good reason why I havent used tables in such a long time

Comment: @Toskan don't give up on tables, I got exactly what you're looking for in [**Demo 2**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54423309/2813224). table 300px wide (150px cells), a solid 50px line at the bottom of each cell (if only wanted one you can rove one or both and a minor margin adjustment. Text always flows to the top of both cells and the line is stuck to the bottom permanently. Also if you click a `td` while pressing the `[CTRL]⌘] .key you can edit the text and fill up the cells with as much dynamic text as you want. the table should handle the text with the cells expanding vertically.

Comment: @zer00ne does that work in IE11? screw it, i'll just accept your answer, you put a good effort into it. It is quite weird to use tags like that though. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Nested Elements Controlling Content

### and Reinforcing Table Behavior

#### Sub-table and Sub-cells

Keep in mind it is valid and common practice to place any element in any amount in a `<td>` (if you are concerned about standards, semantics, etc.) 
**Each `<td>` has:**

> **Sub-table: `<figure class="content">`**
>   With `display: table`, this acts as a sub-table. As such, it controls the exterior of it's child element's text-wrapping, overflow, and aspects derived from it acting as a table and the child a table-cell. It also controls the height of the table itself and stabilizes dimensions by conforming to its own dimensions.
>
> ---
>
> **Sub-cell: `<figcaption class='text'>`**
>   `display: table-cell` imposes *cell behavior* on the `<figcaption>` so it will expand vertically as content increases and keeping its text within its borders.
>
> ---

---

#### Miscellaneous

- `vertical-align: top;` on `td` for content to occupy the top of each cell.
- There are two solutions concerning the `.separator`.

  - **Demo 1** `<figure>` has the `border-bottom` colored green. Although it definitely stay at the bottom, I realized that it's 3 times longer than the original.
  - **Demo 2** `.separator` is a `<hr>` 50px wide. In order to keep it at the bottom, it is pinned under `<figure>`.
- Because the importance of the table containing dynamic content, I added an event handler that triggers when the table is clicked with a <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key pressed. The cell clicked by the user becomes editable. When reviewing the demo, try filling the table with the intent on breaking it ... bet you can't

---

### Demo 1

**Details are thoroughly commented in demo**

```js
// CTRL + Click to Edit Text 
/* 
|| - This is not required it is for demonstration purposes.
||   This is to simulate dynamic content. 
|| - Press the ctrl key + click with mouse/pointer device on 
||   either cell to edit the text.
*/
var table = document.querySelector('table');

table.onclick = edit;

function edit(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('text') && e.ctrlKey) {
    if (!e.target.classList.contains('edit')) {
      e.target.contentEditable = true;
      e.target.classList.add('edit');
    } else {
      e.target.contentEditable = false;
      e.target.classList.remove('edit');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
/*
|| - Collapsed borders and fixed layout gives us a degree control.
|| - 100% x 100% makes the tbody, tr, and to some extent td
||   stretch to their borders.
*/

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}


/*
|| - vertical-align: top aligns each of the cells' content to the
||   top.
*/

td {
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  vertical-align: top;
}


/*
|| - This is a figure tag within each td. It stabilizes
||   dimensions of the td it's nested in by always being at 100% 
||   of the td height (not its own height). 
|| - Note it has display: table and fixed layout. having a nested
||   tabled within a real td gives us more control and less
||   unpredictable behavior.
|| - The word-* and overflow properties are applied here because
||   the figure is the buffer between the text of the figcaption
||   and the td that they all reside within.
|| - The .separator is actually the bottom border of the figure. 
||   This ensures that the green line is always at the bottom of
||   each cell. Note that the color of the line on the left is 
||   red. That was intentional in order to show that they were 
||   separate.
*/

.content {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  word-break: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  border-bottom: 0.5ex solid rgba(0, 200, 0, 0.75);
}


/*
|| - This is the figcaption nested within each figure. Having 
||   display:table-cell allows the figcaption to expand vertically
||   when the text increases.
|| - The padding is in ch units. Ch size is relative to the font.
||   I don't se the advantage IMO but as a rough equivalent to a 
||   character's width, ch seems to be the closest.
*/

.text {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 1ch 0.75ch 1ch 1ch;
}


/*
|| This is the red line previously mentioned
*/

td:first-of-type figure {
  border-bottom: 0.5ex solid rgba(200, 0, 0, 0.9);
}


/*
|| - The remaining rule sets are for the demonstration they are
||   not required nor suggested.
*/

b {
  font-size: 15vh;
}

kbd {
  border: 2px outset grey;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 2px 3px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <figure class='content'>
        <figcaption class='text'>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </td>
    <td>
      <figure class='content'>
        <figcaption class='text'>
          commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
          <p style='color:green'>To edit text on either cell:</p>
          <p>PC: <kbd>ctrl</kbd></p>
          <p>or</p>
          <p>Mac: <kbd>&#8984;</kbd></p>
          <p><sup>&#10133;</sup> <b>&#128432;</b></p>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

### Demo 2

**Details are thoroughly commented in demo**

```js
// CTRL + Click to Edit Text 
/* 
|| - This is not required it is for demonstration purposes.
||   This is to simulate dynamic content. 
|| - Press the ctrl key + click with mouse/pointer device on 
||   either cell to edit the text.
*/
var table = document.querySelector('table');

table.onclick = edit;

function edit(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('text') && e.ctrlKey) {
    if (!e.target.classList.contains('edit')) {
      e.target.contentEditable = true;
      e.target.classList.add('edit');
    } else {
      e.target.contentEditable = false;
      e.target.classList.remove('edit');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
/*
|| - Collapsed borders and fixed layout gives us a degree control.
|| - 100% x 100% makes the tbody, tr, and to some extent td
||   stretch to their borders.
*/

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}


/*
|| - vertical-align: top aligns each of the cells' content to the
||   top.
*/

td {
  width: 150px;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}


/*
|| - This is a figure tag within each td. It stabilizes
||   dimensions of the td it's nested in by always being at 100% 
||   of the td height (not its own height). 
|| - Note it has display: table and fixed layout. having a nested
||   tabled within a real td gives us more control and less
||   unpredictable behavior.
|| - The word-* and overflow properties are applied here because
||   the figure is the buffer between the text of the figcaption
||   and the td that they all reside within.
|| - The .separator is a customized <hr>. 
||   To ensure that the green line is always at the bottom of
||   each cell. The <hr> is pinned underneath the figure then 
||   moved vertically up a little by a negative margin from
||   <figure>
*/

.content {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  margin: 0 0 -1vh;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  word-break: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}


/*
|| - This is the figcaption nested within each figure. Having 
||   display:table-cell allows the figcaption to expand vertically
||   when the text increases.
|| - The padding is in ch units. Ch size is relative to the font.
||   I don't se the advantage IMO but as a rough equivalent to a 
||   character's width, ch seems to be the closest.
*/

.text {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 1ch 0.75ch 1ch 1ch;
}


/*
|| This is the red line previously mentioned
*/

.separator {
  width: 50px;
  border-bottom: 0.5ex solid rgba(0, 200, 0, 0.75);
  margin: 0 auto;
}

td:first-of-type hr {
  border-bottom: 0.5ex solid rgba(200, 0, 0, 0.9);
}


/*
|| - The remaining rule sets are for the demonstration they are
||   not required nor suggested.
*/

b {
  font-size: 15vh;
}

kbd {
  border: 2px outset grey;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 2px 3px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <figure class='content'>
        <figcaption class='text'>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
      <hr class='separator'>
    </td>
    <td>
      <figure class='content'>
        <figcaption class='text'>
          commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
          <p style='color:green'>To edit text on a cell:</p>
          <p>PC: <kbd>ctrl</kbd></p>
          <p>or</p>
          <p>Mac: <kbd>&#8984;</kbd></p>
          <p><sup>&#10133;</sup> <b>&#128432;</b></p>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
      <hr class='separator'>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to add `vertical-align: text-top` to the `<td>` element styles.

See the Codepen: https://codepen.io/jaredforth/pen/mvrqGV

Answer (score -2):

`vertical-align: top` can solve your problem, but it won't work for all elements.

You can use `flex` instead of a table. The default text vertical alignment will be to top. It's also consider better practice to use `flex` or `grid` for layout rather then tables.

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
}

.content{
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">short text</div>
  <div class="content">multi<br/>line<br/> text</div>
</div>
```